Surefire doesn't execute tests from the test output directory on higher maven 3.9.6 version
I have upgraded maven from 3.5 to 3.9.6. I have changed no other configuration in my pom.xml or upgraded the surefire version as of yet.
The surefire config in my project pom.xml looks like this:
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/someCodeFolder</soureDirectory>
    <testDirectory>src/test/someTestFolder</testDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/mytests</testDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

When running tests previously, they would be executed from a lib/lib-component/target/mytests level.
Ever since upgrading to maven 3.9.6, tests fail as some of my path references have ../dependency/xyz as it's expected to run from within the target/mytests level.
I know I should use absolute paths, but in this instance, what has changed/could have changed in the 3.9.6 env configuration resulting in tests being executed from the library level, as opposed to the test output directory level?

Why do you even have configuration sourceDirectory, testDirectory etc.? Keep the defaults... also why using an ancient old surefire-plugin (2014-03-12)? Put your tests into src/test/java/<packageName>/ and your production code into src/main/java/<packageName>... remove sourceDirectory, testDirectory and testOutputDirectory from your pom file... also please show the full pom file... because I fear there are things configured which shouldn't be ...

Unfortunately the project I'm working on is using maven specifically to manage and pull dependencies. The base code is not java hence the directories are labelled diff to the defaults. Upgrading surefire is my next move, but that is taking time to get it uploaded to a mirror repo internally. testOutputDirectory can be removed and it would become target/test-classes but they aren't executed from here either.

Please show more of your pom... the question what kind of tests those are? etc. Upgrade plugins version...

Will share some more of what I can tomorrow. They are plain text KDB/q tests. Compiling is not required, it just copies the files and listed dependencies based on the library's pom into the target folder. The code for the tests has references based on the target/test-classes dir. If it needs a resource it has a dependency on then it references ../dependency/xyz. In this new case, since we are not running from target/test-classes the relative path is now invalid.

FYI, I solved this using the workingDirectory option on surefire.
Added
<configuration>
    <workingdDirectory>target/test-classes</workingDirectory>
</configuration> 

to the pom xml for the plugin.
